# ReactiveCommand when TreeView is expanded?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

The [Avalonia TreeView docs](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/treeview-1#:%7E:text=Avalonia-,TreeView,in%20an%20Avalonia%20MVVM%20project.) give us the following XAML code for opening a `TreeView` of files from a directory:

```
<TreeView
    Items="{Binding Items}"
    Width="400" Height="480"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left">

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <TreeDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Subfolders}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding strNodeText}" />
        </TreeDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

The docs load all subfolders upon the start of the app with the recursive `GetSubFolders` method. I refactored that method to an instance method of the `Node` class. Now, I want to only call that method on a `Node` if it is expanded in the `TreeView`, as to not have to load all the files at once. However, I can't find any way for the `Node` model to detect when it has been expanded in the `TreeView`.

How would I go about calling this method properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```xml
<TreeView.Styles>
    <Style Selector="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Style>
</TreeView.Styles>
```

On your class that is the `ViewModel` for each `TreeViewItem`, ensure there is  a bindable property:

```cs
public bool IsExpanded
{
    get { return _isExpanded; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isExpanded, value); }
}
```

Now what you could do this:

```cs
set
{
    if (this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isExpanded, value))
    {
        GetSubFolders();
    }
}
```